# How to configure localization with react router and i18 directly from url as language params?

Tags: localization, internationalization, react-i18next

I am very new to implementing translations to my projects. By reading documentation and following tutorials i am now able to use translation just by defining the language as default one. But what i want to do is, i need to have default language as in english and when i do [www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de) i want to see the german translations of the texts. And i want to only do that through params and not with clicking into any button and translate. I will share some parts of my code below:

i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

// //local imports
import en from "./locales/en.json";
import de from "./locales/de.json";

let language = localStorage.getItem("language");

if (language === undefined) {
  language = "de";
 }

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
 resources: {
   en: { translations: en },
   de: { translations: de },
 },
 fallbackLng: "de",
 lng: "de",
 // debug only when not in production
 debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
 ns: ["translations"],
 defaultNS: "translations",
 keySeparator: false,
 interpolation: {
   escapeValue: false,
   formatSeparator: ",",
 },
 react: {
   wait: true,
 },
});

export default i18n;
```

and in the below i add my react routing in my app component

```
App.js
 <div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={() => <ForgotPassword data={data} />}
      ></Route>
      <Route path="/success" component={Success}></Route>
      <Route
        path="/change-password"
        render={() => <ChangePassword data={data} />}
      ></Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

as of now the language is translated to german by using useTranslation in the components example: {t("Please enter a valid email")} so this is getting translated.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the detection of the language to the path. As [docs](https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils#language-detector) suggest you can give the order as below in the `init` options. Add `i18next-browser-languagedetector` as a dependency and set the order as below.

```js
detection: {
      order: ["path", "localStorage", "htmlTag", "subdomain"],
      lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
      checkWhitelist: true,
    },
```